# What may the reason for force close after the application is closed?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, forceclose

In my application everything is working fine. I have added all the permissions and the activities in the manifest. And i am using a service in my application so i have added that it too in manifest file.

The problem is i am getting force close after the application is closed. Then my background service is restarted so that the saved info in service being lost.

Thinking that there is a problem with the service i have removed service class, from manifest, and from code to start the service. After that too the force close problem exists.

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonPackage.create(AddonPackage.java:152)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.LocalSdkParser.scanMissingAddons(LocalSdkParser.java:279)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.LocalSdkParser.parseSdk(LocalSdkParser.java:142)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.getInstalledPackages(UpdaterData.java:377)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.LocalSdkAdapter$TableContentProvider.getElements(LocalSdkAdapter.java:96)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getRawChildren(StructuredViewer.java:989)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.getRawChildren(ColumnViewer.java:703)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTableViewer.java:1087)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:896)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getSortedChildren(StructuredViewer.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:701)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:649)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:636)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer$2.run(AbstractTableViewer.java:592)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1422)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1383)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:590)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1664)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.LocalPackagesPage.onSdkReload(LocalPackagesPage.java:293)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.LocalPackagesPage.onSdkLoaded(LocalPackagesPage.java:286)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData$6.run(UpdaterData.java:1041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:179)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4584)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.broadcastOnSdkLoaded(UpdaterData.java:1037)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl1.postCreateContent(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl1.java:313)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl1.open(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl1.java:117)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.open(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:153)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.actions.SdkAvdManagerAction.run(SdkAvdManagerAction.java:118)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Comment: What exception message is coming in log? Paste log message here.

Comment: Check your log cat for the exception

Comment: Check your onPause() onStop() and onDestroy() methods and make sure that they don't contain any errors and that they do proper calls to their respective super-methods.

Comment: May be you are doing too much work on your main UI thread thats why exception is coming, Please show logcat so that we can get more information out of it

Comment: use try catch block @ this line AddonPackage.java:152

Comment: That stacktrace be wack, it seems to suggest you're running your application as a java application / applet rather than an Android Application?